# SVN-file not under version control

Tags: svn

I am writing a Perl script for the SVN automation.

I have done the following steps.

1) Using svn checkout , I have copied a sub directory lets say a/b/c which is under svn version control.

2) I copied a user given file "file.txt" to folder "c".
   So lets say I am running this in directory "temp". So my directory structure now is
  temp/c/file.txt

3) Did svn add. It worked properly.
   It showed
   A  file.txt

4) After that I did "svn commit -m adding a file"

But its showing following error

temp/c/a is not under version control

what is "a" here...is it for "file adding" operation.
  and why svn commit is not working.

Thank you

Comment: The directory a file is in should be versioned as well, I gather that's the problem here? A simple output of `svn stat` might clarify the matter.

Comment: The "a" in "temp/c/a" is not same as my directory a (as in a/b/c). What I want to say is whenever I add any file its showing the same error "temp/c/a is not under version control". From a/b/c I checked out only c in temp.so now I have temp/c. In temp/c I have copied a file test.txt.SO I now have temp/c/test.txt. I am running the command svn commit from c directory only, so only c directory gets copied to my svn directory.

Comment: D'Oh: => ... `svn commit -m adding a file` => ` `svn commit -m "adding a file"`, otherwise it looks to commit the `a` & `file` paths with the comment `"adding"`... I was not awake yet ;)

Comment: ohhh..thanks its working...                                          I thought once I give -m option, whatever string is there after -m , it will be considered as a message. Thanks a lot once again.